# receive excel file name as a parameter in SSIS package from .net

Tags: ssis

I've a SSIS package called from .NET and I need to receive a filename as a parameter to use in the connection manager
How can I receive it in SSIS package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/SET` option of `DTSExec` to do this when executing the package. With this, you can set a package variable you defined earlier.

For more information, have a look at [this](http://pragmaticworks.com/help/dtsxchange/index.htm#page=FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20pass%20parameters%20to%20DTS%20or%20SSIS%20package.htm) and the official microsoft help [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can load it from a configuration file (example [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/xml-configuration-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)) and set the name dinamically using expressions (example [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11113/ssis-dynamically-set-flat-file-connection-manager.aspx))